# I have a problem of maplist of prolog program

Tags: prolog

hallo this is my Programm of Prolog

```
mymaplist(_,[]).
mymaplist(P,[X|Xs]) :-
    call(P,X),
    mymaplist(P,Xs).

even(X) :- X mod 2 =:= 0.
```

my problem is could I use (=..)/2 not use call function? and how should I do. thanks

Comment: Using `(=..)/2` in this context is pretty outdated, inefficient and even less versatile. Your `mymaplist/2` is perfectly defined as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `=..`

```
mymaplist(_, []).
mymaplist(P, [X|Xs]) :-
    F =.. [P, X], % creates the compound term P(X)
    F,            % calls P(X)
    mymaplist(P, Xs).
```

Comment: "creates the predicate P(X)" should really be "creates the compound term P(X)". If you do _call(F)_ afterwards it really shows why doing that is a roundabout way of doing what call/2 does in any case. (I really didn't even get what OP wanted to use _univ_ for.)